Discord JS - Message Command in User Bot
I want to make a Discord bot (in node js) that has a context menu command. Only thing is that it's for a user bot (Discord's new feature - installing an app on a discord account).
I currently use this:
await client.application.commands.set([
    new ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
        .setName('transcript')
        .setType(ApplicationCommandType.Message),
]);

And in servers it works perfectly, but in DM nothing shows up... I added the bot on my account using this link: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_ACTUAL_CLIENT_ID and then clicking on the install on my account button. I checked in the authorised apps and it is there with "create commands".
Thank you.

discord.js does not currently support creating user install commands with their builders. To enable user install commands, when posting the command set integration_types to [1] or [0, 1] for guild install as well. You can read more about them here and here.
You can try posting it directly using the rest. Import routes from discord.js.
client.once('ready', ready => {
    ready.rest.post(Routes.applicationCommands(ready.user.id), {
        body: {
            name: "transcript",
            type: ApplicationCommandType.Message,
            integration_types: [1],
        }
    });
});


Hello! Thank you for your answer but I can't get it to work in private DM with another user. This is my command, set to the bot like I did on my example :
    {
        name: 'transcript',
        type: 3,
        integration_types: [0, 1],
        contexts: [0, 1, 2],
    }


Have you actually installed the application on your profile?

Yes I did (and did it again), it has the "create commands" and "send me direct messages" permissions. It still says "no commands available" in a DM

Try the code in my edited answer, you might be having an issue with the discordjs command manager.

Seems to work on servers but still not in DM... I added 0 to the integration types (and added "contexts: [0, 1, 2]")

Nevermind, reinstalling the app seems to have worked, thank you!
